# Rerendering resets fields..sometimes

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im just trying to understand exactly how rendering decides if it does/doesnt remember the input of a variable on rerender. For example. I have one inputfield tied to a field of a custom object:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!MapRequest__c.Email__c}" id="email" />
```

This is wrapped inside a pageblocksection that is rerendered when a button is clicked. If a user types anything into the inputField it is lost once the rerendering occurs. Even though (I believe) the set method of this object is being called with the value they typed.

I have a seperate part of the page that has a checkbox:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!displaySecondSecond}" id="dueDate2">
```

This too is rerendered on a button click, the only difference is this is in an outputpanel instead of a pageblocksection that gets rerendred, and that it is a checkbox with a boolean value instead of a field with an object attribute (String) value.  However if I check this checkbox and then trigger the rerender of it, the checkbox remains checked. Even though (I believe) it is calling the set method of its boolean value the same way the inputField is calling its own set.

What is the difference, I must be missing why one value is persistant through renders but others are not.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I actually just realized its only this one checkbox that is persistent. This checkbox has an actionSupport attached to it that allows it to rerender a different item. As seen here:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!displaySecondSecond}"
        id="dueDate2" label="Type of Standard Map" required="true" rendered="{!displaySecond}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePanel2 " />
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Turns out that by deleting the line for the actionsupport the checbox gets cleared upon rerending, but with the line there It persists through the rerender, even though the line has little to do with it, I must be overlooking something because this makes it even more confusing to me.

Comment: Please confirm that the MapRequest__c is not transient i.e. it a) is coming from a standard controller or b) is stored in a non-transient field and there is no getter that creates a new or cloned instance.

Comment: Umm Im unsure as Im fairly new to this, but at the top of my VF page I have
      <apex:page standardController="MapRequest__c" extensions="myController">

Comment: Then your case is a) so bit of a mystery why it isn't working. If you don't get any suggestions you'll probably need to post more of your page and controller extension.

Comment: I just made an edit to the original post, I managed to make the issue even more confusing.

Comment: Yep I agree with you about that :)

Comment: @user2070057 did you ever figure this out? I'm also hoping to not lose inputs on rerender